# Value not emitting to parent component

Tags: angular

I am trying to send a value from a child to parent component however I see an undefined value coming through.

Here is my code

Child

```
loanAdjustmentSubmitted = new Subject<any>();

if (resp.header.statuscode === "1") {
  this.loanAdjustmentSubmitted.next(resp);
}
```

Parent

```
@Input() loanAdjustmentSubmitted: any;

console.log(this.loanAdjustmentSubmitted);
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need an `@Output()` in your child component. It doesn't automatically map them based on property names. The Tour of Heroes at [angular.io](https://angular.io/tutorial) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input): Send data from *Parent* -> *Child*
- [`@Output`](https://angular.io/api/core/Output) + [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter): Send data from *Child* -> *Parent*

Try the following

**Child (*.ts)**

```js
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() loanAdjustmentSubmitted = new EventEmitter();

if (resp.header.statuscode === "1") {
  this.loanAdjustmentSubmitted.emit(resp);
}
```

**Parent (*.html)**

```html
<app-child (loanAdjustmentSubmitted)="onLoanAdjustmentSubmitted($event)"></app-child>
```

**Parent (*.ts)**

```js
onLoanAdjustmentSubmitted(value: any) {
  console.log(value);
  // use `value` from child component
}
```

Refer the Angular Doc ["Sharing data between child and parent directives and components"](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sharing-data-between-child-and-parent-directives-and-components) for more info.

If you're curious, the Angular [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L64) is only an Angular specific extension of RxJS `Subject`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to send an event to parent component from child component.

1. Event Emitter via @Output attribute [Reference Link](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)
2. By declaring your Subject type
   observable in a service and injecting it in both parent and child
   components via constructor.